# css, js, and image don't work when I use the / (slash) in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

There's nothing effect with my css, js, and image when I load http://localhost/project/book/4

How to make those work to my website?

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule book/([0-9]+)/ book-detail.php?id_=$1
```

Comment: You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: I don't want to change my HTML file, I just wanna use htaccess, but I don't understand how to use that..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use absolute paths OR add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Otherwise you can add this additional rule to fix css/js/image paths:

```
RewriteRule ^book/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Do some investigation by opening your page in Chrome dev tool and see what css/js URLs are showing 404

Comment: Then learn to do some investigation on your end and clarify in question what you mean by **There's nothing effect with my css, js**

Comment: Or can you help me how to make url like this ?http://localhost/project/book/4

I have searched in google about this but there's no tutorial work for my case..

Just one work, but the url be like this http://localhost/project/4_title-the-book
 RewriteRule (.*)_ book-detail.php?id=$1

Comment: Hmm that is different from the problem posted. You need to edit the question first.